Can we prove the identity for $a^n -b^n$ by induction?
We have the identity:
$$\begin{aligned} 
a^n - b^n &= (a-b) \left(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1} \right) 
 \\  &= (a-b)\sum_{j=1}^{n} a^{n-j}b^{j-1}  \end{aligned}$$
Expanding out the terms show that this is true whenever $n \geq 1 $ but I'm wondering if proving it by induction yields any new insight.

The base case when $n=1$ is true so assume the statement is true for some positive integer $k$
In the induction step where $n = k+1$, we have on the right hand side:
$$\begin{aligned}
&= (a-b)\left(a^k + a^{k-1}b + a^{k-2}b^2 + \cdots + ab^{k-1} + b^k \right) \\
&= (a-b) \left[ \left(a(a^{k-1} + a^{k-2}b + \cdots + ab^{k-2} + b^{k-1} \right) +b^k \right] \\
&= (a-b)[a\left(\frac{a^k-b^k}{a-b} \right) +b^k \\ 
&= a^{k+1} - b^{k+1} \text{     as required} 
\end{aligned}$$
So it seems that doing it by induction makes it so you don't have to manually expand the brackets.
